# I met " ImportError (No module named pandas) " when I test pandas

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, import

```
Python 2.7.10 (default, Jul 10 2015, 12:15:16) 

[GCC 4.8.4] on linux2



>>> import pandas

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>

ImportError: No module named pandas




root@sever002:~# nosetests pandas

======================================================================

ERROR: Failure: ImportError (No module named pandas)

----------------------------------------------------------------------

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose-1.3.7-

py2.7.egg/nose/loader.py", line 407, in loadTestsFromName

    module = resolve_name(addr.module)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/nose-1.3.7-

py2.7.egg/nose/util.py", line 312, in resolve_name

    module = __import__('.'.join(parts_copy))

ImportError: No module named pandas
```

Comment: So an obvious question: did you install pandas? And if so, how?

Comment: Sorry,I didn't mention I have already install pandas using "apt-get install python-pandas" .

Comment: sorry I didn't mention I install pandas using "apt-get install python-pandas" at "root".The true problem is :the route problem.In ubuntu system , It is better install site-package in python starting place. then install dateutil.

Comment: Where are we on this question, did you receive your answer ?

Comment: @baowei: Can you maybe accept the answer to mark your question as resolved?

Answer (score 2):

Install `pandas` first, run:

```
wget https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py
sudo python get-pip.py
sudo pip install pandas
```

And then try again to import `pandas`

**EDIT**

Only an observation: you may need to `sudo apt-get install Cython` before `sudo pip install pandas`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. However the fact is : I have tried pip but I can't get installation package when I realized the lack of pandas. This problem was solved by my friend. The true problem is the route problems.

Comment: The answer helped me. That's what was missing for me. Thanks, Uri.